# positioning a compoundDrawable within TextView?

Tags: android

I am setting a compound drawable to a TextView like so

```
txtView1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0,0);
```

The drawable is drawn to the left most position of the TextView. However I want to move it a little bit so that it doesn't sit on the left border of the TextView but it's like 10dip inside. I did some padding by using:

```
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
```

But this pushes the text to move along with the compound drawable to the right by 10dip.

How do I move only the compound drawable by 10dip without affecting the text ?

Comment: you can also set drawable in textview in xml file using android:drawableLeft property.please try this in textview property in your xml file . android:drawablePadding

Comment: anyone has any solution for this !?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Its very simple. Just add the following piece code to your TextView

```
android:drawablePadding="10dip"
```

This adds padding between your text and the image in the TextView.

Comment: Thank you..

How to call click event for this drawable of TextView.?

Comment: You wont be able to get the click event from the drawable. To do so, you would be have to use a separate ImageView along side of the TextView.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to do it dynamically, you can use the method:

```
txtView1.setCompoundDrawablePadding (int pad);
```

Answer (score -26):

Quick fix - `txtView1.setText("  "+<your text>);`

You can put 1/2 spaces.. or best is to extend textview and modify it the way you want. :)

Comment: The recommended way to set whitespace around drawables is to set padding.