# Is it possible to position drawable of TextView to center

Tags: android

I was wondering, how can I position drawable for my `TextView` to center?

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.bomb, 0, 0, 0);
```

The drawable always position to the left. (There is no text)

Even I had specified

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
```

But the above gravity parameter only workable for text, not the drawable.

I prefer not to use `ImageView`, as sometimes I do need to display text.

According to [positioning a compoundDrawable within TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238043/positioning-a-compounddrawable-within-textview), they use a hard coded padding value to shift the left drawable toward left.

Is there a better way, to position it to exactly center?

Comment: sure, dont use compound drawables, use setBackgroundDrawable

Comment: Or use a spanned text to add an ImageSpan.

Answer (score -2):

Either you can go for spanned text with image span as "Sherif" said so that you can Show the image and text on positions you like.

Else in your case you can use a FrameLayout and an ImageView and a TextView.

like :

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView />
    <TextView />
</FrameLayout>
```

So you can position either your Text or image as you need.